# Is a binary rejection from Apple comprehensive?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I recently submitted an iOS app to the App Store and received a binary rejection. The app is quite complex, so I fully expected a rejection after the first attempt. However, the reviewer only found one minor issue, which leaves me questioning whether there is really only one issue or if this is the first in a long string of rejections. Does Apple provide comprehensive feedback when issuing a binary rejection, or do they simply issue a rejection the moment they find a single issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: @Makyen I think that ship has sailed—this post is 2 years old and has already been answered. It's only been viewed 74 times in 2 years. I really don't think anyone cares...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said they simply issue a rejection the moment they find it. They stop the review process immediately after finding any issue. Once you fix the issue they will start the review process again, if they find any new issues again your app will be rejected.

Comment: Thanks Madhu. That's very helpful!